# how to use Google Line Chart API for passing dynamic data in Blackberry application?

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to pass my array data to the URL.

My code is:

```
    String[] pointArray=(String[]) hashtable.get("point");


// where all values are coming from hashtable of my webservice.I want to pass this array as a chart data for line graph.

BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
add(browserField);

String url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?&cht=lc&chco=000000&chds=0,10&chdlp=b&chxt=x,y" +
"&chg=1.04,0,5,1&chds=0,30&chco=3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa&chls=2,4,1&chm=s,FF0000,0,-1,0|s,0000ff,1,-1,0|s,00aa00,2,-1,0" +
"&chs=480x280&chof=validate&chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&chd=t:"+point";

 browserField.requestContent(url);
```

But it gives me this error :

```
The parameter 'chd=t:[Ljava.Lang.String@d297c570f' does not match the expected format.
```

I want to pass my array to this URL for chart data. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In url

```
String url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?&cht=lc&chco=000000&chds=0,10&chdlp=b&chxt=x,y"
+"&chg=1.04,0,5,1&chds=0,30&chco=3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa&chls=2,4,1&chm=s,FF0000,0,-1,0|s,0000ff,1,-1,0|s,00aa00,2,-1,0"
+"&chs=480x280&chof=validate&chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&chd=t:"
+point;
```

Your point is converted with point.toString() and appended to the url in this part

```
"&chd=t:"+point;
```

which is the second time when chd appers in the url. So in effect only the last chd value is considered. And the first which was chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700 is not considered.

If you want to pass chd it has to be in [format](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#text) chd=t:val,val,val where val represents a value from your data. See [an example with a data chd=t:-5,30,-30,50,80,200](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#textformatautoscaling)

and chd should appear only once in the url.

So your code for the url would be this:

```
String url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?&cht=lc&chco=000000&chds=0,10&chdlp=b&chxt=x,y"
+ "&chg=1.04,0,5,1&chds=0,30&chco=3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa&chls=2,4,1&chm=s,FF0000,0,-1,0|s,0000ff,1,-1,0|s,00aa00,2,-1,0"
+ "&chs=480x280&chof=validate&chd=t:"+<comma separated list of values>;
```

Comment: Thanks Marius Zilenas.. Its really helpful to me, my problem is solved with this solution.